# How to bind a drop event to a target using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I`m following a tutorial but i did non understand well how to bind a  bind a drop event to a target using Jquery; if I have this function:

```
    function changeTarget(event, ui){
      $("#target").addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .html("Dropped ")
      .append(ui.draggable.text());
    } // end changeTarget
```

and I use bind() on a Jquery object:

```
$("#target").bind("drop", changeTarget);
```

Why are the parameters not needed to call the function here?

Comment: Because you're passing a reference to the function - the arguments are only passed when the event fires and is detected.

Comment: So the function arguments are automatically passed when the event is "activated"?